# kendo dropdownlist in pop up editor not binding to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel that i use in a grid.
Lets name it DivisionVm

```
public class DivisionVm {

      public int DivisionId
      public string Name
      public DateTime StartDate  { get; set; }
      public string Condition
      ....    
}
```

When I want to update the model I use a custom editor template.Because Condition takes some predefined string values I use a dropdownlist in the template.

```
       @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model=>model.Condition)

      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Condition")
      .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
      .BindTo(new List<ConditionVm>() {
          new ConditionVm() {
              Text = "Red",
              Condition = "Red"
          },
          new ConditionVm() {
              Text = "Green",
              Condition = "Green"
          },
          new ConditionVm() {
              Text = "Green",
              Condition = "Green"
          }
      })

)
```

ConditionVm is just a viewmodel that i use for binding

```
public class ConditionVm
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that when the pop up editor opens it shows the current condition value in the dropdownlist. But if i select another value from the list, kendo does not track the change.So if i press the update button viemodel does not update.If i change  other fields (eg Name) the viemodel is updating but only for these fields.Condition remains the same even if i have selected another value from the dropdown list.

My controller update method is something like this

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult DivisionGridUpdate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest  request, DivisionVm division)
    {

        if (division != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {

           ......

        }


        return Json(new[] { division }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in the grid setting the column of the DDL like a foreing Key?

Like this:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.yourproperty, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["myList"], "Text", "Condition");
```

Controller (here you fill the list wich will be fill the Dropdownlist:

```
 ViewData["myList"] = myList.Select(e => new
            {
                Text= e.Text,
                Condition= e.Condition 
            });
```

And in the pop up editor you just simple:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.yourproperty)
```